# there is no package with name "QL". while installing clisp

Tags: emacs, lisp, common-lisp, clisp, quicklisp

I'm trying to install lisp in my laptop by following the instruction command and steps that is suggested this site : https://grishagin.com/lisp/windows10/2017/01/26/install-lisp-Windows10.html.
I have done following steps :

1. I've extract emacs in my specified directory and add it's bin path to the system variable
   PATH
2. I've created a another new directory named C:\HOME and add it system variable with variable HOME and
   value C:\HOME
3. Clisp 2.48 is installed in my lisp directory and To fix some problem, copied svm.dll out of clisp-
   2.48/libsvm directory into clisp-2.48/full.
4. Place quicklisp.lisp into lisp directory and run following code in clisp

   (load "C:/lisp/quicklisp.lisp"),
   (quicklisp-quickstart:install :path "C:/lisp/quicklisp/")

   this two command worked but when i go from next command : (ql:add-to-init-file)
   It shows this error :- READ from #<INPUT CONCATENATED-STREAM # #>: there is no package
   with name "QL".

Can anyone please help to solve this error and explain how does this all help for lisp to keep working?

Comment: Did you run all the Lisp code in the same image, or did you restart it between runs?   It will only work if you don't restart it during the process.

Comment: @tfb No i didn't restart.

Comment: I think you need to provide a transcript from the clisp run then, as I don't see how this can happen.

Comment: Is there any steps wrong in instruction that is suggested in that website? @tbf

Comment: I've never installed Quicklisp on Windows (or run clisp on windows) but it looks fine.

Comment: Problem occurs while this command is run (quicklisp-quickstart:install :path "C:/lisp/quicklisp/") . The error shows connection time out.

Comment: Well, there you go, you've answered the question!  Fix the timeout and it will work.

Comment: How can i solve this, timeout, error? @tfb

Comment: I have no idea: it's something to do with the networking configuration of your machine or perhaps the network between it and whatever QL talks to.

Comment: thank for all you help buddy @tfb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, in the QuickLisp installation instructions, it says:

```
(quicklisp-quickstart:install)
```

But you include an optional parameter :path "C:/lisp/quicklisp/"

Try it again, without the optional parameter, and see if that works better.

Comment: I have already fix that bug. It was due to connection time out.

Comment: ahh cool, I didn't see an accepted answer, thought it was still open